# Default components for silent installation with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm developing an installation file in Inno setup.
It has 3 different optional components to install when user selects 'custom'.

It works fine, but when `/SILENT` parameter is passed, no component is installed. I suppose because no component is checked.

...here is the code fragment related:

```
[Types]
Name: custom; Description: {cm:instCustom}; Flags: iscustom
Name: full; Description: {cm:instFull}

[Components]
Name: Programador; Description: {cm:cmpProgramador}; Types: full
Name: Usuario; Description: {cm:cmpUsuario}; Types: full
Name: Reporte; Description: {cm:cmpReporte}; Types: full

[Icons]
Name: {group}\{cm:cmpProgramador}; Filename: {app}\Programador\{#MyAppExeNameA}; Components: Programador
Name: {group}\{cm:cmpUsuario}; Filename: {app}\Usuario\{#MyAppExeNameB}; Components: Usuario
Name: {group}\{cm:cmpReporte}; Filename: {app}\Reporte\{#MyAppExeNameC}; Components: Reporte
Name: {group}\Desinstalar MIVES; Filename: {uninstallexe}

[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: Software\UPC; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCU; Subkey: Software\UPC\MIVES
Root: HKLM; Subkey: Software\UPC; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKLM; Subkey: Software\UPC\MIVES
Root: HKLM; Subkey: Software\UPC\MIVES\Settings; ValueType: string; ValueName: InstallPath; ValueData: {app}

; file association depens of the components selected
Root: HKCR; Subkey: .mip; ValueType: string; ValueData: mip_auto_file; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Components: Programador
Root: HKCR; Subkey: mip_auto_file; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Components: Programador
Root: HKCR; Subkey: mip_auto_file\shell\open\command; ValueType: expandsz; ValueData: {app}\Programador\{#MyAppExeNameA} %1; Components: Programador

Root: HKCR; Subkey: .miu; ValueType: string; ValueData: miu_auto_file; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Components: Usuario
Root: HKCR; Subkey: miu_auto_file; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Components: Usuario
Root: HKCR; Subkey: miu_auto_file\shell\open\command; ValueType: expandsz; ValueData: {app}\Usuario\{#MyAppExeNameB} %1; Components: Usuario

Root: HKCR; Subkey: .mir; ValueType: string; ValueData: mir_auto_file; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Components: Reporte
Root: HKCR; Subkey: mir_auto_file; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Components: Reporte
Root: HKCR; Subkey: mir_auto_file\shell\open\command; ValueType: expandsz; ValueData: {app}\Reporte\{#MyAppExeNameC} %1; Components: Reporte

[Files]
Source: {#MyAppExeNameA}; DestDir: {app}\Programador; Flags: promptifolder; Components: Programador
Source: {#MyAppExeNameB}; DestDir: {app}\Usuario; Flags: promptifolder; Components: Usuario
Source: {#MyAppExeNameC}; DestDir: {app}\Reporte; Flags: promptifolder; Components: Reporte
```

I need that one of the three components (component 'Usuario') was installed by default when the `/silent` or `/verysilent` parameter is passed.

I think I have to use `Check: WizardSilent`, but I don't know where. In fact, I tried adding the `WizardSilent` in `Components` section, but nothing happens:

```
[Components]
Name: Programador; Description: {cm:cmpProgramador}; Types: full
Name: Usuario; Description: {cm:cmpUsuario}; Types: full; Check: WizardSilent
```

Neither in the `Files` section:

```
[Files]
Source: {#MyAppExeNameB}; DestDir: {app}\Usuario; Flags: promptifolder; Components: Usuario; Check: WizardSilent
```

Here is what I need:

- `MIVES_211.exe /SP- /verysilent`  >>>  installs "Usuario" component by default (silent mode, and no `/components` parameter)
- `MIVES_211.exe /SP- /silent /components=Reporte`  >>>  installs only "Reporte" component (silent mode, and `components` parameter)
- `MIVES_211.exe /SP- /silent /components=Usuario,Reporte`  >>>  installs "Usuario" and "Reporte" components (silent mode, and `components` parameter)

***EDITED:***
I think I've found one solution, but I don't know if it is a good solution. Just added one new type including the `WizardSilent` check:

```
[Types]
Name: silent; Description: {cm:instCustom}; Check: WizardSilent
Name: custom; Description: {cm:instCustom}; Flags: iscustom
Name: full; Description: {cm:instFull}
```

And use it in the components section, component "Usuario" (the component I want to install by default in a silent installation):

```
[Components]
Name: Programador; Description: {cm:cmpProgramador}; Types: full
Name: Usuario; Description: {cm:cmpUsuario}; Types: full silent
Name: Reporte; Description: {cm:cmpReporte}; Types: full
```

Now, it works really as I want. But I don't like to have two types with the same description, unless only one is showed in the setup wizard.

Is it a good idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your setup is conceptually wrong.

The silent installation should install whatever the typical/default/common installation is. Now it looks like the default installation is the "Full" installation, but you want the silent installation to behave differently. That does not seem right.

So you should have a default "Typical" installation type, with the "Usuario" component. Just like you have the "Silent" type now. But the "Typical" type will make sense even in an interactive installation.

```
[Types]
Name: typical; Description: "Typical"
Name: full; Description: "Full"
Name: custom; Description: "Custom"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: Programador; Description: "Programador"; Types: full
Name: Usuario; Description: "Usuario"; Types: full typical
Name: Reporte; Description: "Reporte"; Types: full
```

---

And anyway, the `/SILENT` should always be accompanied with `/LOADINF` or at least `/COMPONENTS` or `/TYPE`.

---

Your solution with "silent" type, while a hack, will work somewhat, because the `Check: WizardSilent` will hide this type in the interactive installation.

---

*Btw, note that with mere `/SILENT`, when upgrading, the installer will use components selected in the previous (possibly interactive) installation.*

Comment: Thanks, Martin.

It was a bit strange to have two types with the same description , as I had done. It works, but...

...better to have a "typical" type,which will be installed by default in a silent installation.

I will try your solution.